# "Светать" или "Светлеть"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как данное слово правильно пишется? Или можно и так, и так?

Comment: Это два разных слова. Пишутся они именно так, как вы их и написали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и так и так (запятая не ставится).
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/светлеть](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/светать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Но "светать" - только о солнце.

Answer (score 1):

Эти слова различаются не только по смыслу (*светать* - о признаках наступления *рассвета*, *светлеть* - о произвольном предмете, становящемся всё светлее), но и по способу употребления. **Светать** употребимо *только в безличных* предложениях (напр.: *Уже светает*; найденный википедией в мемуарах пример иного употребления - отклонение от нормы), **светлеть** - в любых (с подлежащим или без него).

Comment: Согласна с Вами: светать (как и смеркаться) — особый глагол. Светает, светало — смеркается, смеркалось.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Есть (был) устаревший способ употребления. См. вторую ссылку в ответе oleedd.(вики).

Comment: Да, я знаю об этом. Светать — 2. Становиться светлее, ярче с рассветом. http://www.endic.ru/ozhegov/Svetat-31310.html Крылов — 1832 год; Бунин — 1909 год. Ефремова же дает **только одно значение**, да и Ушаков (1935-1940) — тоже. В современном языке второе значение утратило актуальность. Думаю, его надо признать устаревшим.

Comment: "Светлеть" тоже о наступлении рассвета.в безличных предложениях (см. словари).